# Package org.apache.pdfbox.printing does not exist while running a standalone java program

Tags: java, java-8, java-print

I am using **Jdk-8** in my system and trying to run a standalone java program to validate printing in the printer. The full `PrintTest` class is mentioned below as:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import javax.print.PrintService;
import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;
import javax.print.attribute.HashPrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.Copies;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.Sides;
import javax.print.PrintException;

import javafx.print.Paper;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.printing.PDFPrintable;
import org.apache.pdfbox.printing.PDFPageable;


public class PrintTest{
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            
            try{
                final String path = "C:/projects/printFile.docx";
                File file = new File(path);
                if (!file.exists()) 
                    return;
                PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);
                PrintRequestAttributeSet pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
                pras.add(Sides.DUPLEX);
                PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
                job.setPageable(new PDFPageable(document));
                job.print(pras);
                
                System.out.println("Print completed...");
            } catch(PrintException pe){
                pe.printStackTrace();
            } catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

But I'm getting below errors everytime while compiling from the command prompt `javac PrintTest.java` file.

1. error: package org.apache.pdfbox.printing does not exist
2. error: package org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel does not exist
3. error: package javafx.print does not exist

Not able to resolve these errors. It is not maven project that I can add dependency. Please help to compile and run the program smoothly.

If I commented out the error lines and tried to compile then it ran without any errors. But I need all the lines to be compiled.